# I do like a green tie/ a man in a tuxedo

Tags: meaning, phrasing

I've scoured the internet but couldn't find anything on this. Why this particular way of phrasing? Is there any difference between using the singular and using the plural, that is? For instance " I like green ties" and " I like a green tie".  IS it just a matter of emphasis, or what? Does it imply something that I miss, how does the subtext change?

Comment: It is the difference between "I like lemons" and "I like a bit of lemon in my tea" - it is the specific liking of wearing a green tie or seeing someone wearing it

Comment: The "do" in "I do like . . ." is for emphasis. "I do like a green tie" can be interpreted as "I like a green tie when someone else is wearing it," or "I was passing the tie counter in the store, and a green tie caught my attention; my, do I like a green tie!" The "I like a man in a tuxedo" can be interpreted similarly, particularly when you are looking at a man who is wearing a tuxedo and say, "I do like a man in a tuxedo." You're NOT saying you disapprove of a man in a sport coat, or sweats, or a dashiki, but that to you there is a certain je ne sais qua about a guy in a tux.

Comment: Very slightly, *I do like a green tie* is a flirtatious way of saying *I do like a man in a green tie, which in this case means you, Mr Green Tie*. However, *very slightly* is the operative phrase.

Broadly, this can't be clarified in words alone; it needs tone and pace and such like…